# Multiple check-box selection and create a tag based on selected option and also filter out the data in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to provide multiple selection using `check-box` and depending on that it will create a `tag` using `angular directive`.
If user selects multiple check-box then according to that `tags` should create and if user remove any tag then check-box should be unchecked. So depending on a selection and a removal of tag data should be `filter` out.

Here is my Working [CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/ot7a2qvk/1/)

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Its working? What are you asking?

Comment: @SyntaxRules i want multiple selection using check-box and depending on selection tag should be created...ru getting what im asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//FILTER

```
  .filter('findobj', function () {
 return function (dataobj, multipleVlaue) {
     if (!multipleVlaue) return dataobj;
     return dataobj.filter(function (news) {
         var tofilter = [];

         angular.forEach(multipleVlaue,function(v,i){ 
          tofilter.push(v);
         });

         return news.CategoryList.some(function (category) {
        return tofilter.indexOf(category.DisplayName)>-1;
     });

     });
 };
 })
```

> Here u can refer the [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuvuzd8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for some pre-built code.

You can use [Angular-multi-select](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main) in combination with a custom filter.