# How to access in controller an angular model inside another model?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angular-ngmodel

Every organization has multiple channels. Foreach organization, I display a multiple select box with the channels as options.

```
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="orgModel in selectedOrganizations.selectedOrganizations">
                      <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header"><h3>{{orgModel.name}}</h3></div>
                        <div class="box-divider m-a-0"></div>
                        <ul class="list no-border p-b">
                          <li class="list-item">
                            <div class="list-body">
                              <select multiple name="singleSelect" class="form-control input-c" id="singleSelect" ng-model="org.selectedChannels" ng-options="channel.name for channel in orgModel.channels" ng-show="item.editing">
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
```

Where and how I can access the `org.selectedChannels` in the controller?

Comment: If you are looking for something  [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31846527/4810042) Angular Filter.

Comment: @Mihai Gota, I think, it should be ***ng-model="orgModel.selectedChannels"**, not as you wrote, in order to access selected channels of each organization.
After that, you can access selected channels by this way : **$scope.selectedOrganizations.selectedOrganizations[0].selectedChannels**

Comment: That's right @Natiq . The data is saved into $scope.selectedOrganizations.selectedOrganizations .

Comment: @Mihai Gota, Did you try above code?

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you @Natiq

Comment: @Mihai Gota, you are welcome. Could you mark as **accepted** if I post this comment as answer?

Comment: Of course! Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assign selected channels to each organization you must use ng-repeat variable in ng-model of select element.

```
ng-model="orgModel.selectedChannels"
```

After that, you can access selected channels of each organization by index of organization:

```
$scope.selectedOrganizations.selectedOrganizations[0].select‌​edChannels
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.org.selectedChannels` in controller to access select box value

Comment: By this way, he can only access selected Chanels of only one organization. Isn't it?